# case with router-outlet in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular

This is my case, I have a main login that I configure in my app-routing.module.ts

```
{
  path:'',
  redirectTo:'/login',
  pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
  path:'users',
  component:UsuariosComponent
}
```

my login

```html
<div class="container p-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mx-auto">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          Acceso al Sistema
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <form  (submit)="login()" >
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="user.email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" autofocus>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password"  [(ngModel)]="user.contrasenia" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" >
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
              Ingresar
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

then when logging in to the main component use route.navigate to / main

1. my app.component is like this

   ```
   < router-outlet></router-outlet>
   ```

2.my main is like this main.component.html

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto"><!--mr-auto-->
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/users" routerLinkActive="active">
      <i class="material-icons">person</i>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="salir()" routerLinkActive="active">
      <i class="material-icons">power_settings_new</i>
    </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
 
  

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

my problem comes here when I want to access the routerlink `/users`, the nav or the ul where the routerlink had did not load, it takes me practically to another page, help me pls

[image]

Comment: what do you expect ?

Comment: that under the ul my routerLink runs and not on another empty page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Router-outlet only works for child routes. You need to have something like:

```json
{
  path:'',
  component: Maincomponent,
  children:[
    {
      path: 'users',
      component: Usercomponent
    }
  ]
}
```

And the router-outlet must be located in the parent Maincomponent html file

Comment: you can get what i want :) with son like this
localhost / main / users
is there a way to make it just localhost / users and get the same result?

Comment: It should work with an empty root as well. But if you have a login you will benefit from having ex. /login as the login route and all the ‘secure’ pages within something like ‘/main/...’. With this you can add a Authguard on all the routes beneath ‘main’